# How does these local variables works to avoid race condition?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, race-condition

I came across a snippet of code like this:

```
id target = self.target;
SEL selector = self.selector;
if([target respondToSelector:@SEL(selector)])
{
  [target performSelector:@SEL(selector)];
}
```

and the author gives this explanation:

> We created two local variables to avoid a race condition arising during the following possible sequence of execution:
>
> 1. Invoking `[target respondsToSelector:selector]` in some thread A.
> 2. Changing either target of the selector in some thread B.
> 3. Invoking `[target performSelector:selector]` in thread A.
>
> With this code, even if either target of the selector is changed, performSelector will be called on the right target and selector.

What am I wondering is: which resource is being raced for? And how do these two local variables help to avoid a race condition? I really don't know where the race condition is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In short, they don’t avoid one race condition, but do avoid another.

Comment: then which one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it using local variables to avoid race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142755/is-it-using-local-variables-to-avoid-race-condition)

Comment: That is also asked by me and I didn't get an effective answer. So can you solve my problem?

Comment: Also, if you can link to the snippet you ran across, we might be able to give you better or more specific answers.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a race condition is any situation where multiple threads are

- contending for some shared resources;
- these threads are not synchronizing their access for those resources; and therefore
- the resulting behavior is dependent upon the precise timing or sequence of events in the various threads.

Often race condition problems are tricky to manifest because unlike many other types of bugs, the sequence of events necessary to manifest the aberrant behavior is non-deterministic and can happen very infrequently. But as unlikely as these race conditions may seem, as Apple says in their [Thread Sanitizer and Static Analyzer](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/412/) video, there is no such thing as a benign race condition. (Fortunately, that Thread Sanitizer tool, aka TSan, described in that video can identify many types of data races.)

Coming back to your example, imagine if the following was happening on thread A:

```
if ([self.target respondToSelector:@SEL(self.selector)]) {
    [self.target performSelector:@SEL(self.selector)];
}
```

In this implementation, it is possible that between the time thread A determines that `respondsToSelector` succeeds and when it attempts to `performSelector`, that thread B could have slipped in and changed either the selector or the target to something else. Worse, if thread B changed either of these properties to something that couldn't be performed, the app could crash.

By making copies of these references in local variables, as shown in your original code snippet, the developer eliminates this possibility. Because this routine running in thread A has copies to the target and selector references, it now doesn't matter if B changes the properties between when A checked `respondsToSelector` and when A calls `performSelector`. Thread A can safely use its local variables, eliminating this particular race condition.

But this does not mean that this truly thread-safe:

- First, if multiple threads are really performing unsynchronized access to these two properties, they would have to be, at an absolutely minimum, atomic properties. (I wouldn't do that for reasons I'll describe later, but it's a bare minimum when doing something like in your code snippet.)
- Second, there is a secondary race condition between these two properties. Imagine that `self.target` and `self.selector` refer to some `Foo` object and instance method, respectively. Let's assume that thread A gets the `Foo` target, but before it gets a chance to retrieve the selector, thread B slips in and changes `self.target` and `self.selector` to something for a completely different object, say a `Bar` object. Then thread A then retrieves the `self.selector` which now refers to some `Bar` instance method. Sure, the code in your question probably won't crash if it used local variables to hold the `target` and `selector` (because the `respondsToSelector` of the `Bar` method on the `Foo` target will likely gracefully fail), but it also won't do what you want, either. And that can often be just as bad.
- There are obviously other thread-safety considerations within the target object, itself, too. For example, if that target object is not thread-safe, thread B might be half-way through the process of mutating the target object and it might be in an internally inconsistent state when thread A tries to call the selector method. So, you must confirm whether the `target` object is, itself, thread-safe.

For these reasons, while the pattern in your original code snippet resolves one particular crash that can result from one narrow race condition, it doesn't solve a broader array of other problems. So, the typical solution is to write code that [synchronizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) all access to these separate properties (and possibly other things, too). You can use GCD queues to do this (either a serial queue or reader-writer pattern), or locks or `@synchronized` directive.

And, going back to my earlier comment about atomic properties, if you employ some broader synchronization pattern to achieve a more robust thread-safe solution, that often obviates the need for atomic properties.

Comment: Thank you very much! What you said is largely agreeable with me except one point which confuses me: by creating two local variables, the routine running in thread A copies the reference to target, not the target itself, right? So if anything change in target, a mere copy of reference to it is useless.And, it now does matter if B changes the properties between when A checked respondsToSelector and when A calls performSelector. What is wrong with my this understanding?

Comment: Correct, you're dealing with reference to the target object only. So your code snippet does nothing to address the thread-safety of the target. It offers no protection to B mutating the target, potentially into some internally inconsistent state. Your code snippet is solving one extremely narrow race condition, that `self.target` and `self.selector` that were called for `respondsToSelector` and what they refer to when you actually get around to `performSelect` could be different and could result in a crash. But your question's original snippet doesn't solve a wide swathe of other problems.

Comment: All you said is fully understood. So the author's statement to the code snippet is wrong? This confused me for almost the whole day. Thanks.

Comment: I'm more suspicious about the code than I am about the description. The description describes the intent behind the code reasonably well, but the problem is that the code is solving a single, minor issue and doesn't address the much broader thread-safety issue. But perhaps the author solved this elsewhere. It's impossible to say on the basis of the limited information provided.

Comment: You are right, but it is the very core code intending to show readers how to avoid race condition. But the topic and the whole code segment is about retain cycle instead of thread-safety. Maybe the author just want us to know the existence of race condition and thread-safety.

Comment: Could you help me with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206513/where-is-the-best-place-to-add-constraints-to-custom-tableviewcells  Thanks.