# Where is the best place to add constraints to custom tableviewcells?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I know the best place to add constraints is viewDidLoad, but for a custom view, especially for custom cells, I'd like to hide all these layout details to itself, without exposed to its controller. And I don't want VC to send message to its view, because it contributes a little to coupling, which I hate most.So where should I add constraints, in the init method or layoutSubview, or something else?

Comment: `awakeFromNib` Is good

Comment: not using SB, xib, just programly

Comment: The in the initialiser a super the answer below. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623276-init

Comment: didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not using storyboards, I would say the best place to add your constraints is in the init method of `UITableViewCell`:

```
class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    lazy var subview: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.addSubview(subview)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            subview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            subview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            subview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            subview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 230.0)
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is init the best place?

Answer (score 2):

For `UITableViewCell` subclass, you would generally add the constraints wherever you added the subviews to the view hierarchy.

- For controls in NIB, I'd add the constraints right there in Interface Builder, eliminating the need to do anything programmatically.
- If you are using a NIB, but for some reason choose to not put the constraints in the XIB, itself, you can programmatically create your constraints in `awakeFromNib`. You would not attempt to add these constraints in `init(coder:)`, because those outlets have not yet been hooked up. You'd want to do this in `awakeFromNib`, at which point they are hooked up.
- If you are are using a NIB, but adding some additional subviews programmatically, again, you'd add these subviews and their associated constraints in `awakeFromNib`. If these new subviews don't need any `@IBOutlet` references, you theoretically also could do it in `init(coder:)`.
- If you are not using a NIB, but creating the cell's subviews entirely programmatically, you'd generally do this in either `init(coder:)` or `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` depending upon how `cellForRowAt` instantiated the cell.

  - Nowadays, you'd generally register a class for the table view's reuse identifier and then `cellForRowAt` would just `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`, in which case you'd do this cell customization in `init(coder:)`.
  - Back before iOS had this `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:) method` routine (i.e. we only had the rendition without the `IndexPath` parameter), we'd call `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`, and if it returned `nil`, we'd manually instantiate cells using `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`. But this technique isn't used much any more.
  - For historical perspective, it's worth noting that you may still stumble across old code that adds the cell's subviews right in `cellForRowAt`. But we'd generally prefer to move this cell customization code into the `UITableViewCell` subclass to help minimize view controller bloat.

Bottom line, where you add constraints wherever you add your subviews to your view hierarchy, and which method you put this in is dependent upon how you are instantiating your cells.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! My tableview is add to the hierarchy in viewDidLoad, so all the subviews' constraints are add when and there. But I still have on puzzling, which is whether adding multiple constraints to multiple subviews  will increase init time significantly?

Comment: @HongJian - If you add your table view in `viewDidLoad`, then only the constraints between the table view and its superview should be added in `viewDidLoad`. The constraints for the cell don't belong there, though. Do that as outlined above.

Comment: I met up with an odd situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227732/app-finishes-running-without-going-to-a-global-breakpoint  sorry to ask for your help again.

Comment: FYI, adding the necessary and sufficient constraints does not add init time significantly. And the benefit of reusable cells is that you aren't doing this too many times, regardless.